# Site icon on iOS app has a circular background

Tags: bug, design

When viewing the site on the main web, the site icon bookmark is only the bookmark itself.

When viewed on the iOS app, it has a beige circle surrounding it (light grey for Meta), which seems incongruous when compared to the other site icons... plus, it does not match the icons on the full site.

Could this please be fixed so that the icon is the same (without the background circle)?

I can't add an image at this minute but will do so when I get home unless someone else does it for me.

Update:

OK... now things are just getting weird... On the main version of the site, I'm still seeing the bookmark only version of the icon...

[image: Bookmark Only Icon]

But now, on the iOS version, I see the proposed icon:

[image: iOS view of icon]

But I still think it looks odd being in a circle when none of the other icons are in a circle... though, I don't know how I would fix it because without the circle, the icon probably wouldn't be visible.

As a note, many of the sites you see in this list... their icons appear in circles in their site logos... they just don't in the dropdown.

[image: M&TV logo] [image: Seasoned Advice Logo]

Comment: I'm assuming this is **more** caching; the favicon was only updated 12 hours or so ago, and it took a while for it to propagate on the web.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  possible... Still hasn't updated.